# UISearchbar not taking any inputs when added as UIView subview

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

didBeginEditing is calling but UISearchbar is not taking inputs as UIView subview same thing with UITextfield and UISearchTextfiled

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search pokemon"
    searchBar.delegate = self
    self.addSubview(searchBar)
    
    searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
        searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
        searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 100),
        searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44)
    ])


extension InitialView : UISearchBarDelegate{
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print("did begin")
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        print("search \(searchText)")
    }
}
```

PS : I tested in device, keyboard is not showing `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` method is calling

Comment: Could you show the entire code for `InitialView`

Comment: Is this a cell?

Comment: No , just UIView